# How to convert MySQL query result to JSON object?

Tags: python, mysql, json

Goal is to migrate some crucial data from MySQL db to a NoSQL document based db. To make the process simpler, I assume it's best to first convert mysql query result to JSON object. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Okaaay. Well how? This isn't a homework problem. I've been scratching my head for a few hours...

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have so far. Quite frankly, that would help your question gain more traction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your SQL query's result set `row`s contain 4 values each, you just need to give these fields names and create a dict to insert into your NoSQL databse.

```
fieldnames = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
dict_row = dict(zip(fieldnames, row))
```